# Quiero traer la fecha de todos los registros y compararla con la fecha actual?

Tags: python, django

Hola¡ Quiero poder traer la fecha de todos mis registros para compararle con la fecha actual para así saber cuantos días lleva registrado cierto producto pero no se como hacerlo alguien que me ayude por favor.

No se si me hago entender es algo como

```
fechaactual = Datetime.now()

fecharegistro = Empaque.objects.values('fecha')
```

Pero a la hora de mostrarlo solo me muestra el ultimo

Comment: Ya lo estás haciendo. Todos tus registros están en `fecharegistro`.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que necesitas hacer es:

```
Empaque.objects.filter(fecha__lt=Datetime.now())
```

Debieras mirar esta parte de la documentacion

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

fecha_actual = datetime.now()
registros = Empaque.objects.all()

for registro in registros:
    delta = fecha_actual - registro.fecha
    registro.dias_desde_registro = delta.days
```

Comment: Si me sirve pero quiero que lo haga con todos los registros pero cuando lo muestro somo me muestra el ultimo como puedo hacer para que me lo muestre en todos

Comment: De esta forma lo hace con todos los registros que recibe de Empaque.objects.all(), que son todos los que haya en la base de datos.
`{% for registro in registros %}
    {{registro.dias_desde_registro}}
{% endfor %}`

Comment: No me funciona me sigue mostrando solo el ultimo registros

Comment: Pega por favor el views.py y el .html en la pregunta para ver mejor donde está fallando.

Comment: Hola gracias ya lo pude solucionar

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solución para lo que estaba buscando espero le sirva a alguien.

Estas es mi vista:

```
def inventarioempaque(request):
        empaque = Empaque.objects.all().order_by('fecha')
        fecha = Empaque.objects.values('fecha')

    #Codigo para calcular fecha actual
    fechaa = strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    #Codigo para calcular hora actual
    hora = strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    fecha_actual = date.today()
    registros = Empaque.objects.all().order_by('fecha')

    for obj in empaque:
        delta = fecha_actual - obj.fecha
        obj.dias_desde_registro = delta.days

    return render(request,"inventario/empaque.html",{'empaque': empaque});
```

Esta es mi plantilla:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Fecha empaque</th>
                        <th>Hora</th>
                        <th>Variedad</th>
                        <th>Grado</th>
                        <th>Empaque</th>
                        <th>Comercializadora</th>
                        <th>Cantidad de ramos</th>
                        <th>Unidades por ramo</th>
                        <th>Celda</th>
                        <th>Dias en empaque</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for obj in empaque %}
                    {%if obj.dias_desde_registro >= 12 %} 
                    <tr style="background-color: #FC3041">
                        <th>{{obj.fecha}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.hora}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.variedad}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.grado}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.empaque}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.comercializadora}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.ramos}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.unidades}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.celda}}</th>
                        <th >{{obj.dias_desde_registro}}</th>
                    {% else %}
                        <th>{{obj.fecha}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.hora}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.variedad}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.grado}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.empaque}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.comercializadora}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.ramos}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.unidades}}</th>
                        <th>{{obj.celda}}</th>
                        <th >{{obj.dias_desde_registro}}</th>
                    {% endif %}
                </tbody>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No se entiende bien que es esta respuesta, si estas agregando información, por favor borra la respuesta y edita la pregunta agregando la información ahí mismo. Ahora, si hallaste la respuesta a tu pregunta y estas publicándola, por favor explica como has solucionado el problemas (el código no lo es todo) para que otros puedan beneficiarse de ella. Salu2

Comment: Esta es la solución a la pregunta que hice

Comment: Probaste la solución http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/25342/14464 ?